# Do I need to waterproof fastener holes on the exterior of my home?

Tags: waterproofing, exterior, rain

This is a general question that relates to a number of small DIY projects I want to do around our house, including

- putting an awning over one of our door ways to keep rain away from the doorstep/foundation
- hanging a string of outdoor lights with a small solar panel

If I use regular wood screws to screw things into the exterior wall of my house, is there anything I need to do to water proof the hole like add sealant or anything? In both cases, the screw should be under the awning/gutter, but I am still not sure about rain in the wind or just general moisture.

I hope that makes sense - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what the holes are _in_. What type of siding are we talking about?  "Regular wood screws" are likely to rust and stain. Any outdoor fasteners should be corrosion resistant.

Comment: The screws will be going into wood. I am not the handiest person on earth, so I am not sure if there are different types, but I am happy to provide a picture if that would help as well. I have heard some people mention silicon filling or something, so I wasn't sure...

Comment: It shouldn't take much Googling to determine what kind of siding you have. Or post a photo. It's hard to give specific answers with vague information. Please put all new information _in your question_, not down here.